# ERROR: Cannot initialize Map Fragment UNKNOWN HERE SDK

Tags: android, here-api, mapfragment

I just wanted to test the Here-SDK 3.4.0_165. I took this project  https://github.com/heremaps/here-android-sdk-examples/tree/master/3d-venues-and-indoor-routing and used the manifest from here https://github.com/heremaps/here-android-sdk-examples/blob/master/map-rendering-android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml#L32 (with other package name) added the aar to the libs folder and entered the appid, apptoken, license key to the manifest. Now when i start the app i got the error:

`ERROR: Cannot initialize Map Fragment UNKNOWN`

Did i miss something? When i put the 3.4.0_165 aar in some old project which had 3.3.0_503 before i get the same error. Revert it to 3.3 everything works fine. Is there something broken in 3.4? I use the premium SDK

Update:

Now for no reason i get 
`ERROR: Cannot initialize Map Fragment MISSING_LIBRARIES`. I changed nothing. My build.gradle looks like this:

`dependencies {
    compile(name: 'HERE-sdk', ext: 'aar')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
}`

Comment: Seems like the error ERROR: Cannot initialize Map Fragment MISSING_LIBRARIS  only occurs on Samsung devices on a Nexus 6 everything works fine

Answer (score 0):

As i remember you should specify different mapService process for versions:

- 3.3: use global.Here.Map.Service.v2
- 3.4: use global.Here.Map.Service.v3

Comment: Yeah i did this.